# Want to ask if my answer is correct

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Okay, this started out as a question on what the questions mean, but I found out the answer midway while typing, not wanting to waste my keystrokes, I'm asking if my answers are correct instead.**

(b) 
You are in a project group of 4 persons which needs to complete 20 tasks. Each task is assigned to one person; hence, each person is assigned 5 tasks.

i) How many possible ways of assigning all tasks are there? ($3$ marks)

$$\frac{\frac{20!}{5!5!5!5!}}{4!} = 488,864,376$$

ii) There are two tasks which you particularly dislike. How many possible ways of assigning tasks are there where you are assigned both of there tasks? ($3$ marks)

$$\frac{\frac{18!}{3!5!5!5!}}{3!} = 102,918,816$$

iii) The project group randomly decides - with equal probability among all the possible ways - on one way of assigning the tasks. What is the probability that you are assigned both of the tasks which you dislike in Q1.(b)(ii)? ($4$ marks)

$$\frac{102,918,816}{488,864,376} = 0.211$$

iv) The project group decides that, instead of the method in Q1.(b)(iii), they will repeatedly choose a task at random and assign it to a member, until all the tasks are chosen. Each task has the same probability of being chosen at each time, and a task that has been chosen is removed from the set of tasks to choose from the set of tasks to choose from.

Given this method of assigning tasks, what is your probability of being assigned both of the tasks which you dislike? ( $4$ marks)

\begin{align*}
P & = \frac{2}{20}\\ 
Q & = \frac{18}{20}\binom{20}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{20}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac{18}{20}\right)^{18} = 0.285
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually, the "hence" in the problem statement ought to read "and", because what follows is not a consequence of what precedes it

Comment: In i) why did you divide by $4!$?

Answer (score 1):

(i) You already had the correct result, but then you divide by $4!$ for an unknown reason ...

(ii) The same, i.e., the division by $3!$ is uncalled for

(iii) Would be right if you had parts (i) and (ii) right

(iv) Why would this be different from (iii)?

Comment: Well, I actually follow this: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~amiller/2513/review/CountingProblemsAnswer.pdf  see Q32 and 33. And for the last one, I figure it is a discrete random variable.

Comment: Okay, I did an experiment, and the 4! and 3! are not needed.